# CQLSH: Converting unix timestamp to datetime

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am performing a cql query on a column that stores the values as unix timestmap, but want the results to output as datetime. Is there a way to do this?

i.e. something like the following:

```
select convertToDateTime(column) from table;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm trying to remember if there's an easier, more direct route.  But if you have a table with a UNIX timestamp and want to show it in a datetime format, you can combine the `dateOf` and `min`/`maxTimeuuid` functions together, like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT datetime,unixtime,dateof(mintimeuuid(unixtime)) FROM unixtime;

 datetimetext   | unixtime      | dateof(mintimeuuid(unixtime))
----------------+---------------+-------------------------------
     2015-07-08 | 1436380283051 |      2015-07-08 13:31:23-0500

(1 rows)
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT datetime,unixtime,dateof(maxtimeuuid(unixtime)) FROM unixtime;

 datetimetext   | unixtime      | dateof(maxtimeuuid(unixtime))
----------------+---------------+-------------------------------
     2015-07-08 | 1436380283051 |      2015-07-08 13:31:23-0500

(1 rows)
```

Note that timeuuid stores greater precision than either a UNIX timestamp or a datetime, so you'll need to first convert it to a TimeUUID using either the `min` or `maxtimeuuid` function.  Then you'll be able to use `dateof` to convert it to a datetime timestamp.