# Convert Timestamp to date using Cassandra query

Tags: cassandra

I need to convert timestamp '1998/02/12 00:00:00 to data 1998-02-12' using Cassandra query. Can anyone help me on this.
Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **toDate** function in cql to get date out of datetime. \

For example, if your table entry looks like:

```
 id          | datetime                        | value
-------------+---------------------------------+-------
 22170825421 | 2018-02-15 14:06:01.000000+0000 |  50
```

You can run the following query:

```
select id, datetime, toDate(datetime) as day, value  from datatable;
```

and it will give you:

```
 id          | datetime                        | day        | value
-------------+---------------------------------+------------+-------
 22170825421 | 2018-02-15 14:06:01.000000+0000 | 2018-02-15 |  50
```

Comment: To get both date and time, you may use `dateof(mintimeuuid(unixtime))`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31301133/1097104

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly in the Cassandra, as it accepts data as `YYYY-mm-dd`, so you need to use some other method (depending on language that you're using) to convert your string into this format.